# Showing multiplication inequality using induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, induction, products

Use induction to show that:
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}\dots \frac{2n-1}{2n} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}
$$
for $n > 1$.

Comment: What are your thoughts/progress so far?

Comment: What is your problem with this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's write this formally. For $n > 1$,
$$ \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2k} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}
$$
Initial case: Substitute $n = 2$ and use a calculator.

Inductive hypothesis:
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{2k-1}{2k} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n-2}}
$$

Inductive step:
$$ \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2k} = \frac{2n-1}{2n} \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{2k-1}{2k} < \frac{2n-1}{2n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n-2}}
$$
Flipping and throwing $(2n)/(2n-1)$ into the square root, (We need to show that the following is $\geq\sqrt{3n+1}$)
$$ \frac{2n}{2n-1} \sqrt{3n-2} = \sqrt{\frac{(3n-2)(4n^2)}{(2n-1)^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{12n^3 - 8n^2}{4n^2 - 4n + 1}}
$$
Preforming polynomial long division, the last term is equal to
$$ \sqrt{3n+1 + \frac{n-1}{4n^2 - 4n + 1}} \geq \sqrt{3n+1}
$$
Since $\frac{n-1}{4n^2 - 4n + 1} > 0$. Therefore,
$$ \frac{2n-1}{2n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n-2}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}
$$

Comment: You can also solve it as: $P(n)\Longrightarrow P(n+1)$ instead of $P(n-1)\Longrightarrow P(n)$ by definition.

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis I'm more used to the latter due to programming backgrounds.